# utilizar Like con multiples columnas

Tags: php, laravel

Estoy buscando de una u otra forma datos en mis columnas

```
$search = Notificaciones::
                where('canal', 'LIKE', '%'.$canal.'%')
                ->where('region','LIKE', '%'.$region.'%')
                ->where('cadena','LIKE', '%'.$cadena.'%')
                ->get();
```

Esto es funciona, mi problema es que las columnas son string y vienen divididos los datos por `comma`

> ejemplo de formato

```
sur,centro,occidente
```

Cuando intente utilizar por ejemplo `SQL>..LIKE .. (sur,centro)` no me muestra nada a pesar de que en mi tabla se encuentre solamente `centro`.

Alguien sabe como a pesar de que le envié una cadena completa, busque en ella como en el ejemplo, que estoy enviando una cadena separada por commas, pero en mi columna solo se encuentra uno de esos valores.

Comment: Y si primero separas la cadena con un explode? haces una busqueda uno a uno

Answer (score 1):

En la laravel la funcion where hace referencia a la clausula `and` de sql
 para `or` debes usar `orWhere`
Ejemplo:

```
$search = Notificaciones:: where('canal', 'LIKE', '%'.$canal.'%')           
                        ->orWhere('region','LIKE', '%'.$region.'%')      
                        ->orWhere('cadena','LIKE', '%'.$cadena.'%')        
                        ->get();
```

Comment: recuerda siempre agregar una explicación, pues solo poner código se considera de baja calidad